# TypeError: sort_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by' - Pandas 1.1.3

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to print the top one value for each group in "2015" column.

input

```
media = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,6),
                     index=['NYT', 'NYT','NYT', 'WSJ', 'WSJ', 'Forbes'],
                     columns = ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'])
```

code

```
def top_one(df, n=1, column="2015"):
    return df.sort_index(by=column)[-n:]

media.groupby('media').apply(top_one)
```

Comment: Did you mean `sort_values`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `sort_index` sorts values by dataframe index. What you want to do is to sort values by some columns. In this case you need to use `sort_values` method.

Comment: It gives me an extra index. Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: It is not creating new index, but maintains the original one. You can use `df.reset_index(drop=True)` to reset it

Comment: That removes all indices.